# php codeigniter - error when inserting

Tags: php, codeigniter

Getting this error while inserting, any solutions? Much appreciated.

```
Error Number: 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`2013evccor`.`tblregister`,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_Register_tblMembers1` FOREIGN KEY (`intMemberID`) REFERENCES
  `tblmembers` (`intMemberID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

INSERT INTO tblregister (intMemberID, intMeetID) VALUE ('','1')
```

model

```
function getReg($meetid) {

    $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');

    $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tblregister
                                (intMeetID, intMemberID)
                                VALUE ('$meetid','$userid')");
```

Comment: You have a foreign key relationship defined on this table, and the record you're inserting does not have a matching record in the foreign table(s). e.g. `intMemberId` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying to add/update a row to table2 that does not have a valid value for the  field based on the values currently stored in table1. If you post some more code I can help you diagnose the specific cause.